# Can you exclude a single dependency automatically created by rpmbuild?

Tags: rhel, rpmbuild

I'm using `rpmbuild` to create an custom rpm to install python3.9 from source. `rpmbuild` automatically creates dependencies for things that it determines are necessary via means described [here](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html). It is possible to disable that completely by setting `AutoReqProv: no` in the spec file as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319798/rpmbuild-where-do-dependencies-i-didnt-specify-come-from) post.

My issue is that for a reason I've not been able to determine, rpmbuild automatically creates a dependency on the file `/usr/local/lib/python`, which I do not want to exist. That file is not created when building the Python3.9 from source and in the event that another rpm does want to install that file, I don't want to have an unnecessary file conflict. Is there any way to specifically tell rpmbuild to **not** create a dependency for that file and **only** that file, while still allowing all of the other automatically generated dependencies to be created?

Spec file for reference:

```
Name: python39
Version: 3.9.0
Release: 1
Summary: Python 3.9

%global _python_bytecompile_errors_terminate_build 0
%define install_dir /usr/local
Source0: Python-3.9.0.tgz

BuildRequires: libffi-devel

%define debug_package %{nil}

%description

%prep

%setup -c -q

%build
umask 022
cd Python-3.9.0

./configure
make
sudo make install

%install
%{__rm} -rf %{buildroot}
%{__mkdir_p} %{buildroot}
%{__cp} -a %{install_dir} %{buildroot}%{install_dir}

%files
%{install_dir}/bin/2to3
%{install_dir}/bin/2to3-3.9
%{install_dir}/bin/easy_install-3.9
%{install_dir}/bin/idle3
%{install_dir}/bin/idle3.9
%{install_dir}/bin/pip3
%{install_dir}/bin/pip3.9
%{install_dir}/bin/pydoc3
%{install_dir}/bin/pydoc3.9
%{install_dir}/bin/python3
%{install_dir}/bin/python3-config
%{install_dir}/bin/python3.9
%{isntall_dir}/bin/python3.9-config
%{install_dir}/include/python3.9
%{install_dir}/lib/libpython3.9.a
%{install_dir}/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.9-embed.pc
%{install_dir}/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.9.pc
%{install_dir}/lib/pkgconfig/python3-embed.pc
%{install_dir}/lib/pkgconfig/python3.pc
%{install_dir}/lib/python3.9
%{install_dir}/share/man/man1/python3.1
%{install_dir}/share/man/man1/python3.9.1

%doc

%post

%postun

%changelog
```

Comment: Can you provide your SPEC file?

Comment: I've added the SPEC file as requested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your spec file.

1. First, and most important, you should **never** use `sudo make install` when building packages: this will install the packages directly onto your local filesystem, which is never what you want. Depending on your environment could corrupt your existing Python installation or cause other unintended consequences.

   The whole idea behind RPM is to build packages as an unprivileged user; privileges should only be required when *installing* the package.
2. The erroneous dependencies are probably being added due to the `cgi` module, which includes this comment at the top of the file:

   ```
   #! /usr/local/bin/python

   # NOTE: the above "/usr/local/bin/python" is NOT a mistake.  It is
   # intentionally NOT "/usr/bin/env python".  On many systems
   # (e.g. Solaris), /usr/local/bin is not in $PATH as passed to CGI
   # scripts, and /usr/local/bin is the default directory where Python is
   # installed, so /usr/bin/env would be unable to find python.  Granted,
   # binary installations by Linux vendors often install Python in
   # /usr/bin.  So let those vendors patch cgi.py to match their choice
   # of installation.
   ```

   RPM sees that `#!/usr/local/bin/python` and adds it as a
   depdendency. The solution is to follow the instructions in the
   comment and patch the file to explicitly reference
   `/usr/local/bin/python3.9`.
3. Avoid having to `cd` into a directory to get your build to work. By
   modifying the arguments to `%setup` this becomes unnecessary.
4. Don't just run `make install`; you want to install files into your
   buildroot. For GNU-like packages (including Python) you can do this
   by setting `DESTDIR` when you install things:

   ```
   make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT
   ```

   This simplifies your `%install` section.
5. RPM will attempt to byte-compile the Python modules using
   `/usr/bin/python`. If you're building this under something like
   CentOS 7, then `/usr/bin/python` is Python 2.7 and will fail with
   syntax errors on many of the files.

   It looks like you've tried to address this by setting
   `_python_bytecompile_errors_terminate_build` to `0`, but at least
   in my test environment this wasn't effective.

   I ended up following [these
   instructions](https://pagure.io/packaging-committee/issue/755) to
   remove the bytecompile step from the postinstall.

All of this gives me:

```
%global _python_bytecompile_errors_terminate_build 0
%define install_dir /usr/local
%define debug_package %{nil}

%global __os_install_post %(echo '%{__os_install_post}' | sed -e 's!/usr/lib[^[:space:]]*/brp-python-bytecompile[[:space:]].*$!!g')

Name: python39
Version: 3.9.0
Release: 1
Summary: Python 3.9
License: Python
Source0: Python-3.9.0.tgz
BuildRequires: libffi-devel
BuildRequires: zlib-devel

%description

%prep
%setup -q -n Python-3.9.0

%build
umask 022

./configure --prefix=%{install_dir}
make

%install
make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT

# Patch cgi.py as described in its comments
sed -i 's,/usr/local/bin/python,/usr/local/bin/python3.9,' $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{install_dir}/lib/python3.9/cgi.py

%files
%{install_dir}/bin/2to3
%{install_dir}/bin/2to3-3.9
%{install_dir}/bin/easy_install-3.9
%{install_dir}/bin/idle3
%{install_dir}/bin/idle3.9
%{install_dir}/bin/pip3
%{install_dir}/bin/pip3.9
%{install_dir}/bin/pydoc3
%{install_dir}/bin/pydoc3.9
%{install_dir}/bin/python3
%{install_dir}/bin/python3-config
%{install_dir}/bin/python3.9
%{install_dir}/bin/python3.9-config
%{install_dir}/include/python3.9
%{install_dir}/lib/libpython3.9.a
%{install_dir}/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.9-embed.pc
%{install_dir}/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.9.pc
%{install_dir}/lib/pkgconfig/python3-embed.pc
%{install_dir}/lib/pkgconfig/python3.pc
%{install_dir}/lib/python3.9
%{install_dir}/share/man/man1/python3.1
%{install_dir}/share/man/man1/python3.9.1

%doc

%post

%postun

%changelog
```

When I build this package on CentOS 7, the resulting dependencies are:

```
$ rpm -qp --requires RPMS/x86_64/python39-3.9.0-1.x86_64.rpm
/bin/bash
/bin/sh
libcrypt.so.1()(64bit)
libcrypt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.10)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.13)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.6)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.9)(64bit)
libdl.so.2()(64bit)
libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libffi.so.6()(64bit)
libm.so.6()(64bit)
libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libnsl.so.1()(64bit)
libnsl.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libpthread.so.0()(64bit)
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit)
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.3)(64bit)
librt.so.1()(64bit)
librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libutil.so.1()(64bit)
libutil.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libz.so.1()(64bit)
libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.0)(64bit)
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
rtld(GNU_HASH)
/usr/bin/env
/usr/local/bin/python3.9
```

To build this on my Fedora 35 system, I had to additionally disable the `brp-mangle-shebangs` post-install process (because it would erroneously replace `/usr/local/bin/python3.9` with `/usr/bin/python3.9`), which looked like:

```
%global __os_install_post %(echo '%{__os_install_post}' | sed -e 's!/usr/lib[^[:space:]]*/brp-python-bytecompile[[:space:]].*$!!g' -e 's!/usr/lib[^[:space:]]*/brp-mangle-shebangs[[:space:]].*$!!g')
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. This is such a comprehensive answer, thank you!

Comment: coming back to this to say that I recently ran into an issue with `brp-mangle-shebangs` in a different rpmbuild and was able to use your answer again. Thanks!